# no. of permutation of number from 1 to n in which i >i+1 and i-1

Tags: algorithm, math

for a given N how many permutations of [1, 2, 3, ..., N] satisfy the following property.

Let P1, P2, ..., PN denote the permutation. The property we want to satisfy is that there exists an i between 2 and n-1 (inclusive) such that

Pj > Pj + 1  ∀   i ≤ j ≤ N - 1.

Pj > Pj - 1  ∀   2 ≤ j ≤ i.

like for N=3

```
Permutations [1, 3, 2] and [2, 3, 1] satisfy the property.
```

Is there any direct formula or algorithm to find these set in programming.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

there are ans perm. and ans is as follows

ans equal to  2^(n-1)  and
 ans -= 2
as it need to be in between 2 <=i <= n-1 && we know that nC1 ans nCn = 1

Comment: srry i dont understand plz explain it.

Comment: taking your example N = 3;

Comment: at N= 3 , we have 3 place to fill up as we know last element cant occupy by the largest element (ie. 3) and at the same 1st place either so we are left with n-2 places to fill n-2 place use binomial coff. nC1 + nC2 + nC3 as in this case we have only one place so we left with nC1 i.e. 2C1

Comment: why 2c1 not 3C1 since N=3

Comment: because your last element not need to be arrange take this case N = 4;

Comment: as N = 4 [1 2 3 4] possible perm. are [1 4 3 2] [1 , 2 , 4 , 3] [1 ,3 , 4, 2] , [1, 3 ,4 , 2] , [2 ,4 , 3 , 1] ...[2 ,3 , 4 , 1] just see the pattern we have to arrange 1 position then 1 & 2 both  and then 1 & 2 & 3 so we have ans = 3C1 + 3C2 + 3C3 .

Comment: oh sorr y it should be 3C1 + 3C2 not 3C3 is not included

Comment: [3,4,1,2] can also be possible

Comment: Pj > Pj + 1 ∀ i ≤ j ≤ N - 1 .  
Pj > Pj - 1 ∀ 2 ≤ j ≤ i. so [3 , 4 , 1  , 2] is not possible

Comment: This is not very clear. Please consider explaining it better *in the answer itself*. Also, it seems like English may not be your native language, so it would probably be best to avoid trying to abbreviate words.

Answer (score 2):

There are `2^(n-1) - 2` such permutations. If `n` is the largest element, then the permutation is uniquely determined by the nonempty, proper subset of `{1, 2, ..., n-1}` which lies to the left of `n` in the permutation. This answer is consistent with the excellent answer of  @גלעדברקן in view of the well-known fact that the elements in each row of Pascal's triangle sum to a power of two (hence the part of the row between the two ones is two less than a power of two).

Here is a Python enumeration which generates all n! permutations and checks them for validity:

```
import itertools

def validPerm(p):
    n = max(p)
    i = p.index(n)
    if i == 0 or i == n-1:
        return False
    else:
        before = p[:i]
        after = p[i+1:]
        return before == sorted(before) and after == sorted(after, reverse = True)

def validPerms(n):
    nums = list(range(1,n+1))
    valids = []
    for p in itertools.permutations(nums):
        lp = list(p)
        if validPerm(lp): valids.append(lp)
    return valids
```

For example,

```
>>> validPerms(4)
[[1, 2, 4, 3], [1, 3, 4, 2], [1, 4, 3, 2], [2, 3, 4, 1], [2, 4, 3, 1], [3, 4, 2, 1]]
```

which gives the expected number of 6.

**On further edit:** The above code was to verify the formula for nondegenerate unimodal permutations (to coin a phrase since "unimodal permutations" is used in the literature for the `2^(n-1)` permutations with exactly one peak, but the 2 which either begin or end with `n` are arguably in some sense degenerate). From an enumeration point of view you would want to do something more efficient. The following is a Python implementation of the idea behind the answer of @גלעדברקן :

```
def validPerms(n):
    valids = []
    nums = list(range(1,n)) #1,2,...,n-1
    snums = set(nums)
    for i in range(1,n-1):
        for first in itertools.combinations(nums,i):
            #first will be already sorted
            rest = sorted(snums - set(first),reverse = True)
            valids.append(list(first) + [n] + rest)
    return valids
```

It is functionally equivalent to the above code, but substantially more efficient.

Comment: Nice, concise answer.

Comment: @גלעדברקן Your's is nice too. It is surprising how often in combinatorics you can get the same answer in different ways.

Comment: ur saying that there are 2^(n-1) such permutation then for n=3 there are 4 permutation but for 3 there are 2 such permutation

Comment: @NickyManali I didn't pay enough attention to the part about 2 and n-1. The basic logic is the same, but you need to throw away both the empty subset of `{1,2...,n-1}` and the whole set as valid subsets to the left of `n`, reducing the overall count by 2.

Comment: @NickyManali How so? 2^(3-1) - 2 = 4-2 = 2.

Comment: ya i tried ur sol but for other value it's giving wrong ans.I appreciate help may be there more needed.

Comment: for n=4 there should be 8 but according to ur ans it is 6

Comment: `[[1, 2, 4, 3], [1, 3, 4, 2], [1, 4, 3, 2], [2, 3, 4, 1], [2, 4, 3, 1], [3, 4, 2, 1]]` are the 6 that I got through a brute-force Python enumeration. Which 2 am I missing?

Comment: i solve it by permutation it is also giving 6 ,but i dont why it is giving me wrong ans.

Comment: Perhaps you misstated the condition. If it is simply ascending before and descending after, it should be 6 rather than 8.

Comment: but such condition is not given like in above example for N=3 it is [2,3,1] and [1,3,2] so for N=4 ans should be 8

Comment: If it is 8 rather than 6, then 2 permutations are missing from the list. What are they? There are only a total of 24 to examine.

Comment: i am extremly srry u r absolutly right i got the correct ans...thannxx and plz tell me the topic so that i can understand this topic fully

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at an example:

```
{1,2,3,4,5,6}
```

Clearly, any positioning of `6` at `i` will mean the right side of it will be sorted descending and the left side of it ascending. For example, `i = 3`

```
{1,2,6,5,4,3}
{1,3,6,5,4,2}
{1,4,6,5,3,2}
...
```

So for each positioning of `N` between `2` and `n-1`, we have `(n - 1) choose (position - 1)` arrangements. This leads to the answer:

```
sum [(n - 1) choose (i - 1)], for i = 2...(n - 1)
```

Comment: i understand ur answer but not fully plz explain it more

Comment: @NickyManali which part can I help you understand better?

Comment: can u plz tell me which topic this question belongs

Comment: @NickyManali "algorithm", "math" and "permutation" seem like ok topics to me. This question might be a good fit for math.stackexchange.com too.